# Getting PHP IP in weird format

Tags: php, ip

Format for some of the ips are in this form

```
2600:646:8381:b627:71c1:bdf8:d
```

Code im using to retrieve ip

```
function get_ip_address(){
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key){
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true){
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip){
                $ip = trim($ip); // just to be safe

                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false){
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Getting same values if I just use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. Dont know why it does this for some ips or what format this is. It wont matter if client returns same value in this format because I just need a unique identifier. Thanks.

Comment: It's ipv6 and as long as you are set up to store it, it will work the same as regular IPv4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) is here ;)

This is a "new" format of IP addresses.